# Битрикс выводит товары из неактивной категории

Tags: php, битрикс, url

На сайте на Битрикс , для вывода одного товара используется компонент `bitrix:catalog.element` . Путь до детальной страницы выглядит вот так

`http://mysite.ru/catalog/Категория1/ТоварДетально`

Проблема в том что `Категория1` не активна. Если перейти по `http://mysite.ru/catalog/Категория1/` получаю 404 страницу. Но если по `http://mysite.ru/catalog/Категория1/ТоварДетально` то попадаю на страницу товара.

Почему так происходит? и как сделать так чтобы если категория не активна, товары в ней тоже были не активны?

Comment: Проверьте активны ли товары в разделе? Вообще штатно если вы в админке деактивируете раздел, то вместе с ним деактивируются и товары. В вашем случае этого не произошло. Каким образом вы деактивировали раздел?

Comment: Проверьте параметр "Показывать деактивированные товары" - "SHOW_DEACTIVATED" должно быть Y.

Answer (score 1):

По умолчанию компонент показывает элементы вне зависимости от того, правильно указан раздел или нет в адресной строке. Чтобы включить строгую проверку существования активного раздела элемента нужно указать в компоненте параметр STRICT_SECTION_CHECK => Y, или DETAIL_STRICT_SECTION_CHECK => Y, если вы используете комплексный компонент bitrix.catalog